Nucleo-f439zi HardFault_Handler() when writing to FIFO for USB_OTG
I am trying to code the USB_OTG from scratch for nucleo-f439zi (STM32F439ZITbu).Microcontrollers_Reference_manual.
At this point I have set up the endpoints and I can receive and read the setup packets the Host sends from the FIFO  (the nucleo is set up in device mode).
When i try write any data to the FIFO the HardFault_Handler() gets triggered.
defining the FIFO address to write to:
 #define USB_OTG_FIFOTX (*(__IO uint32_t *)(USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE +USB_OTG_FIFO_BASE ))

The function im calling to write to the FIFO:
  void USB_OTG_Send_IN_Packet(uint8_t n/*endpoint*/, volatile short *data /*uint8_t *data*/, uint16_t length) 
{

//PAGE 1368 IN data transfers  Packet write++++++++++++++++++
        USB_OTG_FS_DIEPTSIZ0 = ( 1 << USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos);
        USB_OTG_FS_DIEPTSIZ0 |= (/*length*/0x40 & USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_XFRSIZ);
        // Wait until the IN endpoint is ready (TxFIFO not full)
        while ((USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_PTXFE) != USB_OTG_GINTSTS_PTXFE){}
    //1
        while ( USB_OTG_DIEPINT_TXFE == 0x0){}
    
    //READ  DTXFSTSx TO DETERMINE AVAILABLE FIFO
    
    //-------------------------------------
    
        uint32_t tx_fifo_status = USB_OTG_FS_DTXFSTS0;
    
        //DTXFSTS0 returns the value 0x200
    
    if(lock==0){ lock=1;
    //  USB_OTG_FIFO(0) = data; // Write the 32-bit word to the FIFO
    //----------------------------------------------------------------manual copy
        
            // Correct way to assign a memory address to a pointer
            volatile uint32_t* fifo = (volatile uint32_t*)USB_OTG_FIFOTX ;//(0);
    
if(lock==0)
{ 
    lock=1;

    // Correct way to assign a memory address to a pointer
    volatile uint32_t* fifo = (volatile uint32_t*)USB_OTG_FIFOTX ;//(0);

    volatile uint32_t *target= fifo;
    *fifo = 0x12;//This is just a test to see if i can write something very simple.
    //After the above command im getting to the HardFault_Handler().
    lock=0;
}
else
{
    lock=0;
}
    
    
    //2) Enable the endpoint to transmit IN data
    
    USB_OTG_FS_DIEPCTL0 |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_CNAK ; // Clear NAK
    USB_OTG_FS_DIEPCTL0 |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_EPENA; // MODIFY BEFORE ENABLING
    }

How can I write data to the FIFO without triggering the HardFault_Handler?
This is how I am calling the function since replying to a Device Descriptor request is the ultimate goal.
USB_OTG_Send_IN_Packet (0,(volatile short*)USB_GetDeviceDescriptor(),sizeof(USB_DESCRIPTOR_DEVICE));


This isn't an electrical engineering issue, but a simple C pointer usage issue.
The macro does not give you the address of fifo you want to access via a pointer so it does not do what you want it to do.
The macro returns a value that is data read from fifo address. Which can be anything, and then you use that value as pointer where you write 0x12.
